# Eclipse's .ini settings don't seem to be helping me change the max heap size

Tags: java, out-of-memory

Here is my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m
```

Default stuff.  However, I have an app that appears to be crashing with 64 mb of heap size.  I'm printing out the heap size (in bytes) every few seconds until it crashes, and here's the last output:

66650112
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang etc

I'm using Sun's java.  Is there another place I need to set the maximum ram available to java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to say your app crashes with an out of memory error, in this case you should provide [JVM args](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html#nonstandard) to the app settings the heap size, not to eclipse

they look like this:

```
-Xms256M;-Xmx512M
```

Answer (score 5):

These settings are valid for the eclipse platform itself. An application, that's started from within eclipse lives in a separate JVM and that has a default heap size of 64 MB.

It's easy to solve: navigate to the **Run Configuration** of your application, choosen the **Arguments** tab and add the VM parameters, like `-Xmx128M` to the **VM arguments** field.