# Eclipse - Java Heap error while in interface

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am pretty new to eclipse and it was working fine but now its giving me Java Heap problems and sometimes outofmemory issues...

Can anyone help me with my eclipse.ini ... i have increased some memory values and it got better but not perfect...

I am using this java but currently not doing java editing as such i am just in the eclipse interface ..

1.6 1.6.0_16    http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se    C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe        true

Here is my ini, its very small currently

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-nl en_US
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: How about trying mine? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Comment: this is great!, it seems to work, i edited my location where my java was and removed -data ... and all is ok :-)!! Thanks .. I have no idea what it does but it works :-)

Comment: Hey, i can't accept you as the correct answer as its only a comment.  Would like you like to enter a reply so i can accept.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap issues have been seen before (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334102/eclipse-memory-settings-when-getting-java-heap-space-and-out-of-memory), or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413150/eclipses-ini-settings-dont-seem-to-be-helping-me-change-the-max-heap-size), for instance).
Various settings have been proposed ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477871/eclipse-ini-configuration)), since heap size [can be specified in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852781/why-do-we-have-to-increase-the-java-heap).

After quite a bit of experimenting with eclipse.ini, I found my version of it stable enough for most current usage.
See [**Eclipse Galileo 3.5 and 3.5.1 settings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) (as part of various other [eclipse optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957488/eclipse-optimizations))

Comment: Thanks ! as stated it works great, thanks for your quick response and help.